# GKE Instance Metadata pod logging "Unable to sync sandbox" millions of times

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have enabled Workload Identity on my GKE cluster(s) and noticed that the `gke-instance-metadata` pods started logging an insane amount, with two log lines coming up in particular:

1. `"Unable to sync sandbox "05341100f9a2739c19a9c2772a17d4384005c934882b118f183a83c4cc1d558c": setup not complete: podUID="cbef7961-c864-4f21-8861-45f99b2eee90", ip="""`
2. `""/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/cluster-name" HTTP/200"`

I now have a total of over 348 million log entries over 7 days which is affecting my billing.

Anyone have an idea *why* this is happening, and how to stop it?

Comment: As you are integrating 2 GCP Products [[Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) and [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity)], and this may be causing the issue, I strongly recommend you to reach the [Google Cloud Support Team](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) directly, as they may need to review several of your GCP Project settings to identify the cause.

Comment: I'm seeing something similar as well. Maybe not that many logs, but it is a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spun up a fresh cluster with workload identity enabled.

I used the following log explorer query:

```
resource.type="k8s_container"
jsonPayload.message:"Unable to sync sandbox" 
resource.labels.container_name="gke-metadata-server"
```

and immediately saw the same log message.

It's my understanding that that's a benign message / normal log message that you can / should ignore.

It's triggered by creating pods I ran `kubectl run nginx --image=nginx`, and immediately saw the message. (I think it's also triggered by pods being deleted as I saw it again when cluster autoscaler scaled down some nodes.)

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/297084117 <-- Please +1 this issue/bug tracker if you see this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72745282/how-to-stop-gke-metadata-server-from-keep-generating-this-log  <-- has a workaround of using log sink